# graphqljs - returning error code 400 because of graphql errors

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

So I sometimes forget to add returned properties to a query i.e.

```
query {
    getSomething(name: "something) // woops forgot to retrieve stuff
}
```

or I just forget what parameters they take but the web console only returns a very obscure 400 error code, which just looks something like this:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8081/creator/item 400 (Bad Request)

Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error: Request failed with status code 400
```

Is there a way to get better details? I know when I do server side testing it gives me the proper details.

Answer (score 0):

All things what you see at the web console is result of JavaScript runtime. I guess, your GraphQL library doesn't parse an answer from server on 4xx codes. You can patch the library or catch the error and parse the answer content. But **troubleshooting errors during JavaScript runtime is expensive**.

So you need find such errors before compiling. There are tools for that:

- During development [WebStorm IDE plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8097-js-graphql) or [Visual Studio Code plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kumar-harsh.graphql-for-vscode)
- During building [GraphQL eslint plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-graphql)

Comment: I just found out it was in the response of the error object.

Comment: Of course you have errors in the server response. For better knowledge what happend at server you can use `formatError` from `apollo server config`.

Comment: the response data does contain what went wrong e.g. `query is missing required field`. And I'm using graphqljs instead of apollo